# How do I complete the square when the $x^2$ has a coefficient greater than $1$?

Tags: quadratics, completing-the-square

For homework we are doing completing the square and a few of them have coefficients greater than one. For example one of the quadratic equations we have to complete the square of is $-2x^2-7x-2$. All we have to do is complete the square and factorize by the way. If you can complete the square of this and explain the process I should be good for the rest of them

Comment: Factor out the coefficient of $x^2$; in your case you get $-2\left(x^2+\frac72x+1\right)$. Complete the square of the quadratic in parentheses, then multiply the original leading coefficient back in.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

$$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca\right)=a\left(\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2+\frac ca-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)=a\left(\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\right)=a\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^2+bx+c=\dfrac{1}{4a}((4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2)-(b^2-4ac))$$